# How to Run Maui Android App On Device Stratup

Tags: android, xamarin.android, maui

I Devleoped small Andriod TV App using Dot Net Maui with .Net Core 8
I Want this App to run after the device boot completed , i tried the follwoing code as BroadcastReceiver class but this dosn't work

```
    using Android;
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Content.PM;
    using Android.Net;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using static Android.Provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds;
    using static Java.Util.Jar.Attributes;
    [assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReceiveBootCompleted)]
    namespace MMusicPlayer.Platforms.Android
    {
    
        [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
        [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
        public class StartReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            public override void OnReceive(Context? context, Intent? intent)
            {
              
            }
    
    
            
        }
}
```

Comment: By saying "this does not work" what do you mean? 
The "OnReceive" Method is never called ?

Comment: this added automatically when I implement BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Nikos Basdanis  I belive I missed some part if could help me

Comment: The "OnReceive" method called by the Android System when the "BroadcastReceiver" receives an intent broadcast that is registered for. So, in your case, the use case is to listen for boot completion event. When the device finishes booting up, the system sends a broadcast with the action "Intent.ActionBootCompleted". Your BroadcastReceiver's OnReceive method is designed to react to this event.

Comment: Ok then how i can run my app after that or is there any other Method?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error APT2263 unexpected element <receiver> found in <manifest>.

This error is likely caused by an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml file or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code file. MMusicPlayer F:\MMusicPlayer\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml 1

Answer (score 1):

1. **Ensure the Permission is Correct** :
   Your permission declaration looks correct. Having the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in your manifest allows your app to listen for the boot completion event.
2. **Implement the App Launch Logic** : In the OnReceive method of your BroadcastReceiver, you need to start your app's main activity. Assuming your main activity is MainActivity, here's how you can launch it:

```
using Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Net;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using static Android.Provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds;
using static Java.Util.Jar.Attributes;

[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReceiveBootCompleted)]
namespace MMusicPlayer.Platforms.Android
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, DirectBootAware = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }]
    public class StartReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context? context, Intent? intent)
        {
            if (intent?.Action == Intent.ActionBootCompleted)
            {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
                startIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context?.StartActivity(startIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. **Update the Android Manifest** : Make sure your AndroidManifest.xml file is correctly configured to include your BroadcastReceiver.

```
<receiver android:name=".StartReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error APT2263 unexpected element <receiver> found in <manifest>.

This error is likely caused by an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml file or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code file. MMusicPlayer F:\MMusicPlayer\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml 1

Comment: @digitala Please read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element): `<receiver>` is contained in `<application>` not in `<manifest>`.